# Can EF Database Transaction be used in a loop?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, transactions

I have a process where I retrieve records from a database periodically, and run 3 operations on each. For each record, the 3 operations must either all succeed, or none at all. In case of a failure on one of the operations, I want the operations that have been already processed for the previous records to be 
committed, so that next time the process runs, it picks up on the record for which one of the 3 transactions failed previously.

I thought of wrapping the 3 operations in a transaction per record, and loop for each record, but I want to ensure that using a database transaction in this scenario is efficient. The following is what  have in mind. Is it correct?

```
    public async Task OrderCollectionProcessorWorker()
    {
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            try
            {
                IList<Order> ordersToCollect =
                    await context.Orders.Where(
                        x => x.OrderStatusId == OrderStatusCodes.DeliveredId)
                              .ToListAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);

                await ProcessCollectionsAsync(context, ordersToCollect);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("Exception in OrderCollectionProcessorWorker", ex);
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// For each order to collect, perform 3 operations
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">db context</param>
    /// <param name="ordersToCollect">List of Orders for collection</param>
    private async Task ProcessCollectionsAsync(DbContext context, IList<Order> ordersToCollect)
    {
        if (ordersToCollect.Count == 0) return;

        Log.Debug($"ProcessCollections: processing {ordersToCollect.Count} orders");

        foreach (var order in ordersToCollect)
        {
            // group the 3 operations in one transaction for each order
            // so that if one operation fails, the operations performend on the previous orders
            // are committed
            using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    // *************************
                    // run the 3 operations here
                    // operations consist of updating the order itself, and other database updates
                    Operation1(order);
                    Operation2(order);
                    Operation3(order);

                    // *************************

                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction?.Rollback();                        
                    Log.Error("General exception when executing ProcessCollectionsAsync on Order " + order.Id, ex);
                    throw new Exception("ProcessCollections failed on Order " + order.Id, ex); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Based on your code, it seems that every operation is running their own transaction (see transaction is created inside foreach loop). If want to achieve something that all should commit or none then move the transaction creation out of foreach loop.

Comment: No, i want all 3 operations within a transaction, and loop that for each order record in the IList. The 3 operations will go where the comment block is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a correct way of doing it, apart perhaps from fact that in catch you should rethrow the exception or do something else to stop progressing on the loop (if I understood correctly your requirments). It is even not necessary to use

```
var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()
```

because

```
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

creates its own transaction. Every change you made is stored in the context and when you call SaveChanges there is transaction made and all the changes are written as 1 batch. If something fails all the changes are rollbacked. Another call to SaveChanges will make another transaction on new changes. Please bear in mind however that in case transaction fails you should no longer use the same context but create a new one. To summarize I would write your method as follows:

```
private async Task ProcessCollectionsAsync(DbContext context, IList<Order> ordersToCollect)
{
    if (ordersToCollect.Count == 0) return;

    Log.Debug($"ProcessCollections: processing {ordersToCollect.Count} orders");

    foreach (var order in ordersToCollect)
    {
        // group the 3 operations in one transaction for each order
        // so that if one operation fails, the operations performend on the previous orders
        // are committed
        try
        {
            // *************************
            // run the 3 operations here
            // operations consist of updating the order itself, and other database updates
            Operation1(order);
            Operation2(order);
            Operation3(order);

            // *************************

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                     
            Log.Error("General exception when executing ProcessCollectionsAsync on Order " + order.Id, ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Right! forgot to stop the loop, will update code accordingly. Also, yes i seem to recall the same thing you mentioned re. SaveChanges creating its own transactions, but was not sure and wanted to confirm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In all versions of Entity Framework, whenever you execute SaveChanges() to insert, update or delete on the database the framework will wrap that operation in a transaction.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: So when can BeginTransaction/commit/rollback be used?

Comment: Imagine you want to have nested transactions. So you execute your every little change in a transaction and saves it separately but then if any loop operation fails you want to revert all the changes to the beginning - then you can wrap your whole loop in outer transaction and with that you can revert all subchanges in one go.

Comment: Clear, thanks a lot. My initial use of transactions was an overkill in a sense.

Comment: i did! but since i have a low rep it doesnt mark it :(